# Email form wordpress site not sending how to fix

Tags: wordpress

I search everywhere on google and on other sites but didn't find the fix, i am having an issue regarding email sending from WordPress website. I am  using contact form 7 since the email sending function was not working in contact form7 i added Mail Bank to send the email from my another email address which works pretty fine in early days now it stop working like it is not sending mail i checked everything from my site everything is fine. I contacted hosting support, unfortunately, i bought the worst hosting in the world they just not receiving my phone calls so i go to their website and add a complaint ticket and got 0 response i sent separately an email and got 0 response what should i do? the error i am getting are as follows:
[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

And when I Connected my domain to my Gmail account in starting it works fine but from the same day when that problem arrived as i mentioned above this stopped working as well... and i am getting this message...
[image: Email Issues as well this image]

Comment: Do you have ssh details? It seems like your 550 port is blocked. Once you unblock it your email issue will be resolved. Add captcha in your form.

Comment: how to unblock that port? kindly tell me and what is ssh am sorry i m a bit new in this

Comment: It is the root user of your server like admin in windows.  Do you have cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshots are confusing.

BrOPF.png. Clearly states: Outgoing mail from 'yourdomain.org' has been suspended.

The server probably has an outgoing mail limiter that has suspended your domain. Did you try to send out many e-mails? Most servers do not allow this, and block you for it (it's spamming behaviour). Note: these blocks usually have a set lifetime, and will be removed automaticly.

---

bVa1N.png. This screenshot (probably from gmail), states you have used incorrect username and password.

*535 Incorrect authentication data*

---

error code 550. Means that the SMTP (outgoing mail) server cannot deliver the mail. **This is not a port!**
Usually port 587 is used for outgoing mail.

---

I cannot give you any further advice without additional info. You need to find a way to contact your hoster, they can tell you what's going on.

Regards, Bjorn

Answer (score 0):

Try installing SMTP plugin for email handling.

[Here is the good one: Wp Mail Smpt](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)

If you don't have any then simply use the google. 
The plugin has links to help you setup the smtp.